# How to combine multiple mailboxes in Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mail.app, imap

My OS is Mavericks.  The mailboxes shown are grouped under headings MAILBOXES, SMART MAILBOXES, ON MY MAC, and MY EMAIL ADDRESS.  I have Sent and Trash under each.  Their contents are not entirely duplicative.  When I go to mailbox/use this mailbox as, the options are grayed out.  In Preferences/Accounts/Mailbox Behaviors all options are checked to 'store messages on server'.  How do I combine these mailboxes?
Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Where exactly do you go to when you try "mailbox/use this mailbox as"

Answer (score 1):

In the Menu Bar, go to Mailbox after selecting the sub-mailbox, one of your Sent folders, for instance, and then choose "Use This Mailbox For…". You can lump the redundancies together this way, but it's true that you will not be able to completely customize all the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The Mailboxes that are created by Mail app can not be modfied.

Only Mailboxes that you created can be modified.

Thus: Inbox, Draft, Sent, Junk, Trash, Archive and "on My Mac mailboxes" can not be modified.